# changing image overlay box content with PHP (multiple images). PURE CSS

Tags: php, css, overlay

I have made a simpe JS FIDDLE with 2 buttons.
When I click the button, an overlay appears in CSS.

How can I keep the same overlay style, but have different content overlay based on which button is clicked?

I'm doing an image gallery, the number of images (or button in this example) will vary.  I want to open different overlay content based on each clicked image (or button).

How can I do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/mib92/twotc3m3/

HTML CODE

```html
    <a href="#overlay" id="open-overlay">Open Overlay 1</a><br>
    <a href="#overlay" id="open-overlay">Open Overlay 2</a>

    <div id="overlay">
        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>

        <!-- I want to change this content with php based on the different overlaybuttons -->
        <h2 style="font-size:35px">Pure CSS Overlay</h2>
        <p style="font-size:22px;">OPEN CONTENT OVERLAY 1</p>

    </div>
    <div id="mask" onclick="document.location='#';"></div> <!-- the only javascript -->
```

CSS CODE

```css
#overlay{ /* we set all of the properties for are overlay */
        height:80%;
        width:80%;
        margin:0 auto;
        background:white;
        color:black;
        padding:10px;
        position:absolute;
        top:5%;
        left:10%;
        z-index:1000;
        display:none;
        /* CSS 3 */
        -webkit-border-radius:10px;
        -moz-border-radius:10px;
        -o-border-radius:10px;
        border-radius:10px;
    }

    #mask{ /* create are mask */
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        z-index:500;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        display:none;
    }
    /* use :target to look for a link to the overlay then we find are mask */
    #overlay:target, #overlay:target + #mask{
        display:block;
        opacity:1;
    }
    .close{ /* to make a nice looking pure CSS3 close button */
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        top:-20px;
        right:-20px;
        background:red;
        color:white;
        height:40px;
        width:40px;
        line-height:40px;
        font-size:35px;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-align:center;
        font-weight:bold;
        -webkit-border-radius:40px;
        -moz-border-radius:40px;
        -o-border-radius:40px;
        border-radius:40px;
    }
    #open-overlay{ /* open the overlay */
        padding:10px 5px;
        background:blue;
        color:white;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:inline-block;
        margin:20px;
        -webkit-border-radius:10px;
        -moz-border-radius:10px;
        -o-border-radius:10px;
        border-radius:10px;
    }
```

Comment: Just to clarify you want to do this in PHP and not have two different overlays? You could split this into two overlays in HTML and use `.overlay` as a class in CSS?

Comment: @redreddington I'm building my gallery (or buttons in the example) using PHP and each button (or image) needs to open the same (OVERLAY STYLE), but different overlay content.  The content will be build with PHP (pull from DataBase.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve and what are the limitations. If my understanding is right, this is easily achievable applying a tabs system,  where the buttons are the tab buttons and the overlay box is the tabs bodies container. Right? You really don't need multiple overlay containers. One is enough.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu In my example, I used buttons to simplify things, but I am building a thumbnail gallery (using PHP). Each image when click needs to open the SAME OVERLAY STYLE, but different Overlay content (build by the PHP, info pulled from DB)

Comment: Yes, I understood correctly. Now tell me why don't you put the contents of all your overlays in one single overlay and hide them all by default. When you click any thumbnail you open the overlay and apply the unhiding class to the coresponding container.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I'm not sure I follow you.. could you show me an example.  you mean I should load all my content into 1 overlay class, and hide that. And when I click on thumb #1 for example, I unhide only the content associated to overlay #1 ?  I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You'd have to tell me why the "no js" requirement first.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I was trying to do it without JS, but if it's easier with JS, then so be it. I don't mind the JS

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use some AJAX in that case, you would want to have a click handler that would submit a request to a PHP file that would then return the content required.

Something like...

```
<a href="#" class="button" data-action="action1">Action 1</a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-action="action2">Action 2</a>

<div id="overlay">

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax(function(){
            url: "action.php",
            method: "get",
            data: {
                action: $(this).attr("data-action")
            }, 
            success: openOverlay(data)
        })
    });

    function openOverlay(html_content)
    {
        // Clear out the overlay
        $("#overlay").html("");

        // Add new stuff in
        $("#overlay").html(html_content);

        $("#overlay").css("display:block");
    }
</script>
```

And then in PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    switch($_GET['action']) {
        'action1':
            $html = "Action 1";
            break;
        'action2':
            $html = "Action 2";
            break;
    }

    echo $html;
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jquery (note I have changed the id's this has to be unique):

```
var text_1 = 'Integer quis tortor ac erat ornare molestie. Vivamus tincidunt erat eros, vitae accumsan sem vehicula congue. Ut eu sem id urna cursus euismod non a justo. Vestibulum in dui sed arcu varius mollis. Donec eget nulla sed augue mattis congue. Mauris venenatis augue sit amet eleifend ultrices.';

var text_2 = 'Etiam quis hendrerit leo. Quisque feugiat euismod purus vel elementum. Vestibulum nec vulputate nunc. Vivamus vitae sollicitudin nisl, ut eleifend diam. Mauris quis ligula arcu.';

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#overlay p').html('')

  $('#open-overlay_1').click(function(){
     $('#overlay p').html(text_1)
  })

  $('#open-overlay_2').click(function(){
      $('#overlay p').html(text_2)
  })
})
```

NOTE thi is just an example to explain how to do it. For your gallery your data has to be loaded with an ajax request and PHP.

https://jsfiddle.net/fyvmy0ea/